# Date and time regular expression with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a regular expression of date and time in the format `dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00`
There is a space between date and time. Time can be any digits. I have a regex for date which is `(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g)`. But i am not getting how can i make a single regex with date and time ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slashes.

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

Example:

```
> "22/11/2014 00:00:00".match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/g);
[ '22/11/2014 00:00:00' ]
```

Comment: could you post the input string?

Answer (score 1):

Just add pattern for time after the date:

```
/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/\d\d\/\d\d/\d{4,4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/
```

Although you might want to add some sanity checks

```
/[01]\d\/[0123]\d/\d{4,4} [01]\d:[0-6]\d:[0-6]\d/
```

This is for US style dates not EU style.

Comment: Your "sanity check" doesn't sanitized anything

Comment: m42, sanity check means things are not complete rubbish, not that they are completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]{2}+[-\/]+[0-9]{2}+[-\/]+[0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}+:+[0-9]{2}+:+[0-9]{2})
```

i think this may help you but it is not perfect.